# Postgres Hierarchy output

Tags: postgresql, hierarchical

im struggling on how to get the correct output using hierarchy query.

I have one table which loads per day all product and its price. during time this can cancel and being activate again.

I believe with oracle we could use the Connect By.

```
 WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (                                                                                                                                                          
select min(event_date) event_date, item_code,sum(price::numeric)/1024/1024 price, 1 AS level     
from rdpidevdat.raid_r_cbs_offer_accttype_map where product_type='cars'  and item_code in ('Renault') 
group by item_code
UNION  ALL  
SELECT e.event_date, e.item_code, e.price, cte.level + 1                                        
from (select event_date, item_code,sum(price::numeric)/1024/1024 price
from rdpidevdat.raid_r_cbs_offer_accttype_map where product_type='cars'  and item_code in ('9859') 
group by event_date,item_code) e join cte ON e.event_date = cte.event_date and e.item_code = cte.item_code
)                                                                                                                                                                                     
SELECT *                                                                                                                                                                                 
FROM   cte where item_code in ('Renault') ;
```

how do i put an ouput where will have the range of each product during time?

if we have the data:

```
  EVENT_DATE   | ITEM_COD| PRICE
  20210910     | Renaut  | 2500
  20210915     | Renaut  | 2500
  20210920     | Renaut  | 2600
  20211020     | Renaut  | 2900
  20220101     | Renaut  | 2500
```

the expected output should be:

```
-------------------------------------------------
FROM_EVENT_DATE | TO_EVENT_DATE | ITEM_COD| PRICE
 20210910       |  20210915     | Renaut  | 2500
 20210915       |  20210920     | Renaut  | 2600
 20210920       |  20211020     | Renaut  | 2900
 20211020       |  20220101     | Renaut  | 2500
```

Thanks in Advance and Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the solution. Using the Lag and lastvalue function. no need to use the hierarchy one.